# Select in listview, to pass the index through to another form

Tags: c#

```
    public static int iDeliverySelected = -1;
    public static ArrayList myDeliveries = new ArrayList();
```

I specify these two values at the top of the page.

The listview is populated as follows:

```
lstDeliveryDetails.Items.Clear(); 
        foreach (Delivery d in mainForm.myDeliveries)
        {
            ListViewItem item = lstDeliveryDetails.Items.Add(d.DeliveryName); 
            item.SubItems.Add(d.DeliveryAddress);
            item.SubItems.Add(d.DeliveryDay);
            item.SubItems.Add(d.DeliveryTime);
            item.SubItems.Add(d.DeliveryMeal);
            item.SubItems.Add(d.DeliveryInstructions);
            item.SubItems.Add(d.DeliveryStatus);
        }
```

And then when I want to select one of these, I am getting stuck. My idea is that I want to select a value and then click an "Edit" button which will take me through to the saveForm and allow me to edit all the values that correspond to the selected index.

I have tried the following:

```
iDeliverySelected = lstDeliveryDetails.SelectedIndicies;
```

iDeliverySelected = lstDeliveryDetails.SelectedIndex;

They both throw up the following error:

'System.Windows.Forms.ListView' does not contain a definition for 'SelectedIndicies' and no extension method 'SelectedIndicies' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.ListView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I am literally stuck and have no idea what to do next! 
I would really appreciate it if someone could help!

Comment: Using C# in a windows form app

Comment: You'd misspelt SelectedIndices but see my answer below for another way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

In your code in the question after the line

```
ListViewItem item = lstDeliveryDetails.Items.Add(d.DeliveryName);
```

Add the line

```
item.tag = d;
```

Then make your button handler be something like:

```
private void btnEdit_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (ListView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0) 
    {
        saveForm frm = new saveForm((Delivery)ListView1.SelectedItems(0).Tag);
        frm.Show();
    }
}
```

Make the saveForm contain something like:

```
public class saveForm
{
    private Delivery m_delivery;
    public saveForm(Delivery d)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        m_delivery = d;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to pass thru the second form's custom constructor.

```
public Form2()
{
}

int index;
public Form2(int index)
{
    this.index = index;
}

// Code in Main Form
Form2 f2 = new Form2(this.listView1.SelectedIndex);
f2.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: So I have mainForm and saveForm, i want to select in mainForm and find a way to get this in saveForm.

What code would go where?

Comment: The bottom two lines go in mainForm. The top two class constructors for Form2 would be saveForm.   Rename Form2 above to saveForm.